# Suggestion Required in printing the output linklist structure using ncurses

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I have Created a LinkList as follows:

```
vId       msisdn         ivrCode   state     DTMF

9         4321           120005    Talking   #
3         0000           564765    Standby   *
33        1234           120005    Ringing   *
12        1234           1223465   Ringing   3
223       9995373        9995      Pending   4
2         435373         3465      Pending   2
```

Each row here is a node of linklist with elements shown as coloumns.

now in my program I input string using mvscanw function of ncurses and pass it to a function.
This function compares string with ivrCode element of linklist for all list nodes.
If match found then it prints list having that ivrcode using mvpritnw() of ncurses.
If not found it returns.
Now i pass 3465 and hit enter:
So it should Display output as:

```
vId       msisdn         ivrCode   state     DTMF

2         435373         3465      Pending   2
```

But it is not happening:

> here's the code fragment:

```
  void display1(char *r)
 {
char * status;
int   thisDTMF;
char * code;

struct linklist * curser=listhead;
int count;
mvprintw (2,0, "%s","vId");
mvprintw (2,10, "%s","msisdn" );
mvprintw (2,25, "%s","ivrCode" );
mvprintw (2,35, "%s","state" );
mvprintw (2,45, "%s","DTMF" );
count = 4;
while(curser!=NULL)
{ status=getState(curser->state);
  thisDTMF=getDTMF(curser->dtmf);
  code=curser->ivrCode;
  if((code==r)||(status==r))
  { mvprintw (0,0,"%s","m here");
  mvprintw (count,0,"%d",curser->vId);
  mvprintw (count,10,"%s",curser->msisdn);
  mvprintw (count,25, "%s",curser->ivrCode );
  mvprintw (count,35, "%s",status );
  if(thisDTMF==35||thisDTMF==42)
      mvprintw (count,45, "%c",thisDTMF );
  else
  mvprintw (count,45, "%d",thisDTMF );
  count++;
  }
/*else
{mvprintw (3,0, "%s","kuch ni mila" );} */
 curser=curser->next;
}

}


  void rcvChar(char c)
{ char a;
  char *str;
  char *rts=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));

  switch(c)
  { case 'i':   
mvprintw (1,0, "%s","ivrcode:");
mvscanw(1,8,"%s",rts);
mvprintw (1,8, "%s",rts);
//printf("got in rcvchar");
initDisplay();
display1(rts);
dis();
break;
  case 's':
mvprintw (1,0, "%s","state change to ( r,t,p,s) ");
a=getch();
initDisplay();
switch(a)
{case 'r':
    str="Ringing";
    display1(str);
    break;
 case 't':
    str="Talking";
    display1(str);
    break;
 case 'p':
    str="Pending";
    display1(str);
    break;
 case 's':
    str="Standby";
    display1(str);
    break;
 default:
    mvprintw (1,0, "%s","unacceptable State");
    display();
    break;
}
dis();
break;
   }
```

Thus row according to state gets printed.
I guess the problem is that string input from keyboard is not being matched to ivrCode/code.

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

`r`, `status` and `code` are `char *`, but you are testing them with

```
  if((code==r)||(status==r))
```

Try using `strcmp` instead.